# The process cannot access file because it is being used by another process when opening file runtime

Tags: c#

I using following code to create log file and append text at runtime. An I open log file during time. This application show error :The process  cannot access file because it is being used by another process .I want to open log at runtime the project running. How to fix error? 
Thanks.

```
using (var stream = new FileStream(
       path, 
       FileMode.Open, 
       FileAccess.Read, 
       FileShare.ReadWrite))
{
    StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(stream);
    streamWriter.Write(message);
    streamWriter.Close();
    stream.Close();
}
```

Comment: if it's being used by another process check if it's your process or someone elses....

Comment: I want to open it by word to watch during runtime.Sorry my english!

Comment: As per my knowledge, you can not access same file by 2 or more different processes.

Comment: @SarangK: Unless it suffices to open a file in readonly mode. Only one process can write; but multiple processes can read.

Answer (score 0):

If the process that has the file open has opened it and not allowed sharing you really have no proper way of obtaining the contents of that file.

If the operating system is configured to use it you may be able to use VSS ([Volume Snapshot Service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_Copy) aka Volume Shadow Copy) to grab a snapshot of how the file looked earlier but it won't be a live up-to-date view of the current file. For that you need sharing access. How difficult VSS is I have no idea.

But if that other process disallowed shared opening of that file, your only option is to wait for the process to terminate before you try to access that file.

If it is your application that is holding the file then you could change how it opens the file by allowing shared opening of the file through the same file access masks you used in the code in your question.